# Ibeacons sending notification when Android device comes in specific range

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-notifications, iot, ibeacon-android

In my project I want to show the notification on my android device having my android app installed. 
What I actually want to do is that suppose that the person enters the shop I want to show him the welcome notification or any other text from the MySQL database.
Is it possible to do so ? I have searched alot but I am not very well impressed with any solution. 
Can anyone please give me the right tips and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this and it is a common thing to do.  There are two key things you need to know how to do to solve this problem:

1. You need to set up your app to detect beacons and send a notification when the beacon is detected.  You can see an example of how to do this with the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library) here:

   ```
   public class BeaconNotificationApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
     private static final String TAG = "BeaconReferenceApp";
     private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
     private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;

     public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       BeaconManager beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

       // By default the AndroidBeaconLibrary will only find AltBeacons.  If you wish to make it
       // find a different type of beacon, you must specify the byte layout for that beacon's
       // advertisement with a line like below.  The example shows how to find a beacon with the
       // same byte layout as AltBeacon but with a beaconTypeCode of 0xaabb.  To find the proper
       // layout expression for other beacon types, do a web search for "setBeaconLayout"
       // including the quotes.
       //
       //beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
       //beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
       //        setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

       // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
       Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
               null, null, null);
       regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
       backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
         sendNotification();
     }

     @Override
     public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
     }

     @Override
     public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
     }

     private void sendNotification() {
         NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
               new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                       .setContentTitle("Beacon Reference Application")
                       .setContentText("An beacon is nearby.")
                       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

       NotificationManager notificationManager =
               (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
     }    
   }
   ```

You can read more about details of detecting beacons with the Android Beacon Library on the project website.

2. You need to set up a SQL database that stores your beacon messages, then modify the `sendNotification` method above to query that database for the beacon identifiers and show the proper text.  The Android developer website has a good tutorial of how to store date in SQL and retrieve it here:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: what's the purose of and what the MonitoringActivity.class contains **stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MonitoringActivity.class));**

Comment: Sorry, you do not need that code, it was accidentally included.  I removed it from the example.

Comment: **Thanks for help** Actually i was working with _iBeacon_ so needed to set beaconParser. Eventually it worked